# Unable to play video Microsoft media player for html pages

Tags: html, video, media-player, wmv

i am trying to play videos on my site. its working on production. After publishing site on domain player isn't playing videos. Instead its showing msgs on media player bar like
'Preparing to connect', 'Connecting...' and 'Ready', which shows dark screen.

Here is my code of videos.

```
<SPAN id="music1"> 
<OBJECT  style="width:560px; height:300px" id=mediaPlayer
codeBase=http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/
en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701 type=application/x-oleobject
standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..."
style="margin-left: 0px" classid=CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95>
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://microsoft.com/windows
/mediaplayer/en/download/" bgcolor="darkblue" showcontrols="true" 
showpositioncontrols="true" showstatusbar="tue" showgotobar="true"
src="videos/1.wmv" autostart="true" designtimesp="5311"
loop="true" height="600" width="470">
</OBJECT></SPAN>
```

Please let me know, where i am doing wrong, or its domains issue??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your classid imdicates you use MediaPlayer 6.4. What about the people who use a different version? Or no MediaPlayer at all?

Comment: it simply asks user to download plugin for media player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple one:

```
<embed src="videos/1.wmv" width="600" height="470" type="video/x-ms-wmv"></embed>
```

Comment: Yes, I think I read about it. Just drop the whole object stuff and go for a single embed.

Answer (score 2):

Your object doesn't seem to have the source of the video specified. The embed has, but not the  object

```
<SPAN id="music1"> 
<OBJECT  style="width:560px; height:300px; margin-left: 0px" id="mediaPlayer"
codeBase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/
en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701" type="application/x-oleobject"
standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..."
classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95">
    <PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="videos/1.wmv">

<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://microsoft.com/windows
/mediaplayer/en/download/" bgcolor="darkblue" showcontrols="true" 
showpositioncontrols="true" showstatusbar="tue" showgotobar="true"
src="videos/1.wmv" autostart="true" designtimesp="5311"
loop="true" height="600" width="470" />

</OBJECT>
</SPAN>
```

You could also try to let go the object alltogether and just rely on the embed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Yes, the `<video>` tag is new in HTML5 and is currently supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:
`classid=CLSID:clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6`